# SQL syntax : query does not include specified expression X as part of an aggregate function

Tags: sql, ms-access, group-by, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to teach myself SQL, and the task I'm trying to complete is requiring me to list the total amount of mail and freight per month.

My main issue is that I'm getting an error that my expression isn't part of an aggregate function. To deal with that, I tried to include a `GROUP BY` clause, but I am still getting the message about my expression `Month`.

Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT 
    Mnth.mnNm AS Month, 
    Sum(Load.mail) AS TotalMail, 
    Sum (Load.frght) AS TotalFreight
FROM 
    Mnth 
INNER JOIN 
    (Flight 
INNER JOIN 
    Load ON Flight.ftRN = Load.ftRN) ON Mnth.mnID = Flight.mnID
GROUP BY 
    Month;
```

I'm a beginner still struggling with SQL syntax, so any tips are appreciated.

Comment: Google and learn about the GROUP BY clause in SQL.   Googling your error message is also a great resource for teaching yourself SQL.

Comment: Tip: you can write `USING(ftRN)` instead of `ON Flight.ftRN = Load.ftRN` if the column names are the same.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to group by the column, not the alias:

```
GROUP BY Mnth.mnNm
```

Also, Month is a key word, so you should probably put your alias in brackets:

```
SELECT Mnth.mnNm AS [Month]
```